# How can I make my code take in input as a set of tuples and still return the same answer?

Tags: python, list, set, tuples

So I attempted to write two pieces of code, one of them attempts to find whether a sequence of code is a `fourz` or not.

**fourz basically sees whether a card has 4 identical first characters and one nonidentical characters or not.**

For instance,

```
fourz(['3S', '3D', '3C', '3H', '5S']) returns True because there are 4 3 and one 5
fourz(['4S', '3D', '3C', '3H', '5S']) returns False because there are only three 3, and one 4 and one 5.
```

So now I have this code:

```
def is_four_of_a_kind(h):
    h = list(h)
    values = [i[0] for i in h]
    card_order_dict = {'2': 2, '3':3, '4':4, '5': 5, '6':6, '7':7,
                       '8':8, '9':9,'T':10, 'J':11, 'Q':12, 'K':13, 'A':14 }
    count = 1
    rank_values = [card_order_dict[i] for i in values]
    rank_values = sorted(rank_values)

    for i in range(1,len(rank_values)):
        if rank_values[i] == rank_values[0]:
            count += 1
    if count == 4:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

This code correctly returns the output when the code is a **list** but it doesn't work when it's a **set of tuples**

So if my code is like this `fourz({('3S', '3D', '3C', '3H', '5S')}` my code doesn't work..

what changes to my code do I have to make for it to work??

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are defining a tuple inside the set. So only a single element will be in the list when you convert it to list.

For your code to work you can do a simple change in funtion for the conversion to list.

```
def is_four_of_a_kind(h):
if type(h) == set:
    for i in h:
        h = list(i)
else:
    h = list(h)

values = [i[0] for i in h]
card_order_dict = {'2': 2, '3':3, '4':4, '5': 5, '6':6, '7':7,
                   '8':8, '9':9,'T':10, 'J':11, 'Q':12, 'K':13, 'A':14 }
count = 1
rank_values = [card_order_dict[i] for i in values]
rank_values = sorted(rank_values)

for i in range(1,len(rank_values)):
    if rank_values[i] == rank_values[0]:
        count += 1
if count == 4:
    return True
else:
    return False
```